# Can't find a record even when using mongodb's ObjectID in sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

On sailsjs and using mongodb's ObjectID object, I can't findOne() a record in the database with the native mongodb driver.

```
// Included the ObjectID from the mongodb dependency on sails-mongo layer

var mongodb = require("sails-mongo").mongodb;
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;    


// Inside the action2 controller...

var db = sails.getDatastore().manager;

var record = db.collection('event').findOne({_id: new ObjectID(inputs.event.id)});

// Returns an empty object
exits.success(record);
```

I expect to receive a json for the record in the database but I'm receiving an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you aren't getting the value of **inputs.event.id** or you are getting it as other data type and its not generating mongoDB objectId.

Log it and check.

Comment: I managed to get the value from inside the callback of the findOne method. Thanks